# How to do the following diagram in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to do the following diagram
[image]

Here's my try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text width=5em, align=center, inner xsep=0pt]


\begin{figure}[ht] % 'ht' tells LaTeX to place the figure 'here' or at the top of the page
\centering % centers the figure
\scalebox{0.6}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node[block] (A) {A};

\node[block,right of = A] (B) {B};

\node[block,below of = B] (D) {D};

\node[cloud,below of = D] (F) {F};

\node[block,right of =D] (E) {E};

\node[cloud,right of = F] (G) {G};

\node[block,above right of = E] (C) {C};

\node[cloud,right of=G] (H) {H};

\path (A) -- (B) node [midway] {=};

\path (D) -- (E) node [midway] {+};

\path (B) -- (C) node [midway] {+};

\draw[very thick]
(B) edge[below] node{} (D);

\draw[dashed, very thick]
(D) edge[below] node{} (F);

\draw[dashed,very thick]
(E) edge[below] node{} (G);

\draw[dashed,very thick]
(C) edge[below] node{} (H);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

In the picture below, I have difficulties in centring the D and E nodes, and doing the } facing down...
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I'm trying to apply Zarko's answer, but I get the following picture, when I try to write longer strings.

[image]

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Sam thanks for the comment. I've just edited the question to reflect your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Now is considered edited question.

This image reproduce sketch, which you present in the first version of question:

[image]

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing, 
                    calligraphy,% had to be load after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    %\begin{figure}[ht]
    % \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 3mm,
  start chain = going right,
    BC/.style = {decorate,
                 decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
                 raise=5pt},
                 very thick, pen colour={black}
                },
   box/.style = {rounded corners=2pt, draw, fill=blue!20,
                 minimum height=4ex, inner xsep=5pt},
     C/.style = {ellipse, draw, fill=red!20,
                 align=center, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, 
                 inner xsep=-4pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, densely dashed, -Straight Barb}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node[box] (A) {Observation};
\node          {$=$};
\node[box] (B) {Computer Model};
\node          {$+$};
\node[box] (C) {Measurement error};
    \end{scope}
\node[box, below left =of B.south] (D) {Emulator};
\node[box, below right=of B.south] (E) {Bias Term};
\node[below=of B]   {$+$};
% brace
\draw[BC]   (D.north west) -- (E.north east);
% circles
\node[C,below=of D] (F) {Code\\ Uncertainity};
\node[C,below=of E] (G) {Model\\Discrapancy};
\node[C,below=of C |- E.south] (H) {Experimental\\ uncertainity};
% edges
\path   (D) edge    (F) 
        (E) edge    (G)
        (C) edge    (H);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It is unclear (to me), what you like to draw after your asiting of question.

Comment: Hi Zarko, thanks for your answer. However, I still have a doubt. I didn't know, but when I write for example "This text is going to be long" in every figure (box, and circles), they are pictured on top of each other. How can we modify the code to prevent the intersection of the figures?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, well about this your question is not clear. You can prescribe to `box` styles a text width adding option `text width=...`  and `align=center` (for centering content in boxes. However, now longer text can be split into more lines and boxes will not have equal height. Please, show us an example, what is your problem.

Comment: Zarko, I've just updated the question with a picture with my new problem.

Comment: See edited  answer!

Comment: thanks Zarko ;)